# Xamarin.forms - Background color changes when activity is about to load

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, background

I have a `activity` with a `listView` that got items which drive us to another activity called Main Chat. The problem resides when I touch one of those items. Before it loads the respective activity, the background color of the main activity changes to green. I've inspected my code but I can't find any sample of code that does that type of behavior. Here's the video of what happen and the following code:

**Video:** https://files.fm/u/7nt2szdy#/view/20200213_115056.mp4;play

**Sample code of the "click item"**

```
 async void OnListItemClicked(object o, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ((ListView)o).SelectedItem = null;

            var vListItem = e.Item as Classes.ClassConversation.ResultadoConversation;
            var getResposta = await Servicos.Servicos.Token(vListItem.institutionId);

            if (getResposta)
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Chat.MainChat(vListItem, user2, true));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await DisplayAlert(Languages.AppResources.Notifications, Languages.AppResources.ErrorOccurred, "Ok");
        }
    }
```

**Sample code of the Main Chat"**

```
  public MainChat (Classes.ClassConversation.ResultadoConversation conversation, Classes.ClassUser.Result user, bool Resposta)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Muda a cor do texto e o local da tab no android
        UnselectedTabColor = Color.FromHex("#80FFFFFF");
        SelectedTabColor = Color.White;

        //Muda a cor do toolbar e texto 
        if (Resposta == true)
        {
            ((NavigationPage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage).BackgroundColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["colorPrimary"];
            ((NavigationPage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage).BarBackgroundColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["colorPrimary"];
            ((NavigationPage)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage).BarTextColor = (Color)App.Current.Resources["white"];
        }

        if (conversation.OtherUser == null)
        {
            conversation.OtherUser = new Classes.ClassConversation.User();
            if(conversation.user_From.rowKey == user.rowKey)
            {
                conversation.OtherUser = conversation.user_To;
            }
            else
            {
                conversation.OtherUser = conversation.user_From;
            }
        }

        //Set Name and image of the other user and chat title
        if (conversation.OtherUser.photoUri != null)
            ImageUser.Source = new UriImageSource { CachingEnabled = true, Uri = conversation.OtherUser.photoUri, CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(800000, 0, 0, 0) };

        TitleChat.Text = conversation.title;
        NameOtherUser.Text = conversation.OtherUser.name;

        if(Device.RuntimePlatform != Device.iOS)
            Children.Add(new ChatPage(conversation, user));
        else
            Children.Add(new ChatPageIos(conversation, user));

        Children.Add(new Report(conversation, user));

        result = conversation;
    }
```

Comment: from the video provided, the problem relies on the page transiction. It seems that is a "visual glitch", it's probably due to the heavy loading happening or some sort of slow device. the color in the background seems to be the same has your tabview from the MainChat, what happens if you change your tab view color to a static one without binding the colors?

Comment: If i change the binding color of tab bar, the background color is the same color of tab.

I don't think it's an haevy loading because I already used two empty pages and the glitch continues.

Comment: ok so here some things you can try to solve the issue: 1) make a binding to the the tabar IsVisible property, starting at false, and change it until you have all data ready to be displayed. 2) if you are using Prism, try to set the tab colors on the OnNavigatedTo method in the MainChat page. 3) to have a more conclusive understanding of what is happening, you can try to make it navigate to a blank page with a very noticeable color and see if the problem keeps happening, if it doesn't, it's probably a problem in the List page rather than the MainChat page.

Comment: Let me know if any of those thinks worked or what are the behaviours noticed

Comment: didn't saw the comment update, one more thing, is the ItemTemplate of the listview has his color set to transparent? or even the listview itself

Comment: My listView i set transparent background color. In my itemTemplate i dont set a background color.

Comment: try to put the list view background color the same has the page background

Comment: Works better, the background color change, got the same color as the page background.
But on ios it doesn't happen, it waits to load all the information and only then opens it. Here on android you can see the application changing its activity and content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208008/discussion-between-ricardo-dias-morais-and-rafa-vieira).